# mvc kendo grid resize issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a kendo grid in my project,

```
 @(Html.Kendo()
          .Grid(Model)
          .Name("BuilderGrid")
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
           .......................
           .......................
          }).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%; height:100%;" })
```

grid data is loading fine. If I resize the browser window or resize the grid, last 2 or 3 grid rows are not showing, sometimes the last row showing cut .FYI -

[image]

Comment: Can you give a screenshot to show the whole page, just to see how it fits together?

Comment: Hi, pls find below images as per requirement.

Image 1 -  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxTfN.jpg)
Image 2 -  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt8aA.jpg)

Comment: You could remove all of the HTML attribute tags then try it, if it works start to slowly add them back until you have found the problem tag/attribute.

Comment: removed all HTML attribute or styles, but not working. I am using MVC 4. is it supported with Kendo UI?.  If I resize the browser window then showing same issue.

Comment: Here is some information I found about MVC 4 and Kendo: https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: thanks  GeorgeB, I discussed with Telerik Team, and I got an answer. add in code resizeGrid() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. need to add these lines, on page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).resize(function () {
        resizeGrid();
    });
});

function resizeGrid() {
    var gridWidget = $("#BuilderGrid").data("kendoGrid");

    // apply the new height and trigger the layout readjustment
    gridWidget.wrapper.height(847);
    gridWidget.resize();

    // force the layout readjustment without setting a new height
    gridWidget.resize(true);
}
```